# Android get captured image meta data

Tags: java, android, exif

I am trying to capture the latitude of an image that has been captured through the camera and stored into the ImageBox variable. Using the ExifInterface class, I am trying to get the latitude of the image and display that information into the LatitudeBox variable but my syntax is incorrect so please let me know what I am doing wrong! full Code below

MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //variables
    Button CameraButton;
    ImageView ImageBox;
    EditText LatitudeBox, LongitudeBox;
    String IMG = ImageBox.toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
        ImageBox = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        LatitudeBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LatitudeBox);
        LongitudeBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LongitudeBox);

        //Camera Button Onclick
        CameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(IMG);
                    LongitudeBox.setText(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF)); // get longitude
                    LatitudeBox.setText(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF)); //get latitude 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }// try catch 
            }// end onclick 
        });// end camera button onclick





    }// close oncreate

    //display image inside ImageBox variable using bitmap
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == 0)
        {
        Bitmap TheImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageBox.setImageBitmap(TheImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }







}// close main
```

App now crashes on launch and not sure what's causing it. Here is an image of the logcat errors

http://s7.postimg.org/4p67papyj/logcat1.png

activity_main.XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CameraButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:text="@string/Camera_Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LatitudeBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CameraButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/LatitudeBox"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LongitudeBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LatitudeBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/LongitudeBox"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.get()` method for [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html).

```
LatitudeBox = exif.get(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
```

Did you perhaps mean:

```
LatitudeBox.setText(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF));
```

EDIT:

I found it.

Look at the last variable here:

```
Button CameraButton;
ImageView ImageBox;
EditText LatitudeBox, LongitudeBox;
String IMG = ImageBox.toString();
```

You haven't assigned a value to your `ImageView ImageBox`. So when you `ImageBox.toString()`, you receive a `NullPointerException`.

Change initialization of IMG to something like:

```
String IMG = "filename.txt";
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I added the line you gave me which fixed everything but now the app just crashes on load. Not sure whats wrong

Comment: I have edited the main code to add what I've changed

Comment: If it's crashing, could you update your post with the LogCat output?

Comment: Sorry, Here is a picture of the logcat errors when it crashed
http://s7.postimg.org/4p67papyj/logcat1.png

Comment: You've got a `NullPointerException` in that trace. Drop a breakpoint down and debug it to see if you can find which variable it is.

Comment: You're getting there. If you expand `this` in your Variables window, you should be able to see which variables inside your Activity are null at the point of that exception.

Comment: here's the full log for this and i still don't see whats wrong :( http://mar.imghost.us/JxRc.png

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't have your variables in it. Drop a breakpoint down on this line: `CameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);` and step through line by line until you crash. I'm guessing one of your `findViewById()` statements is not resolving the view.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot find whats wrong, I checked line by line so I guess ill just await some more help. Maybe someone can debug it for me since I have no idea what I'm doing. Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you post this: `R.layout.activity_main`.xml?

Comment: I added the layout.xml

Comment: Are you sure this code is right, `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`? Meaning the file name would have to be `activity_main.xml`. Above you posted `Layout.xml`, which would require a change to `setContentView(R.layout.Layout);`.

Comment: Yes the file is activity_main.xml. I corrected it above, sorry about that

Comment: Definitely not. I think I found it, updated my post.

Comment: Still crashes when I changed the initialization to String IMG = "filename.txt"; :/

Comment: Work with me here, you can't just copy/paste what I'm using as an example. That file would have to exist because you need it for the construction of `ExifInterface()` here `new ExifInterface(IMG);`. I suggest you read more documentation on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I understand, as you see in the application, the user takes a picture and the image is should be stored into the variable ImageBox. But I am unsure if ExifInterface can pull the data from ImageBox or it needs a file path?